# Consuming from multiple queue

Tags: go, rabbitmq

I have a rabbit mq instance that I use to listen to changes. However, I have different messages that I need to consume. What I am not sure about now is how to go about it. Would I need to just keep duplicating my Consume method and what is the danger of doing that if any.

```
type Consumer struct {
    conn      *amqp.Connection
    db        *mongo.Database
    queueName string
}

func (consumer *Consumer) setup() error {
    _, err := consumer.conn.Channel()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

// NewConsumer returns a new Consumer
func NewConsumer(conn *amqp.Connection, db *mongo.Database) (Consumer, error) {
    consumer := Consumer{
        conn: conn,
        db:   db,
    }
    return consumer, nil
}

// Listen will listen for all new Queue publications
// and print them to the console.
func (consumer *Consumer) Listen(topics []string) error {

    ch, err := consumer.conn.Channel()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer ch.Close()

    msgs, err := ch.Consume("charge.get", "", true, false, false, false, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    forever := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        for msg := range msgs {
            switch msg.RoutingKey {
            case "charge.get":
                worker.Refund(paymentRepo.NewPaymentRepository(consumer.db), msg.Body)
            }
            // acknowledege received event
            log.Printf("Received a message: %s ROUTIG KEY  %s", msg.Body, msg.RoutingKey)
        }
    }()

    log.Printf("[*] Waiting for message [Exchange, Queue][%s, %s]. To exit press CTRL+C", " getExchangeName()", "q.Name")
    <-forever
    return nil
}
```

Do I just add another `msgs, err := ch.Consume("charge.update", "", true, false, false, false, nil)` below the first one to consume from this queue? Or how can I go about this.